# local variable referenced before assignment frequently occurring error

Tags: error-handling

Hello I've done multiple python programs since I started and an error is occurring quite often for a short time and I don't understand why there is an error or why by just changing random things so the program does the same gets rid of it so can anybody please explain how the "referenced before assignment" error occurs please.

Here's the code with the problem:

```
def compter(sequence, element):
    comtpe=0
    for i in sequence:
        if element==sequence[i]:
            compte+=1
    return compte


compter([1,2,1,1], 1)
```

please explain so I could be able to get rid of it in any future code thank you very much :)

(I'musing python 2.7.6)